# jquery modal: closing a modal and then having it available as a clickable option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I been scratching my head on this one for a while.

Writing a plugin in grails that calls on bootstrap-mini.js and most of its css. Everything works fine. The issue I am having is I have a remote form which onComplete runs java script:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ml-test/blob/master/grails-app/views/mailingListModal/_modalcreate.gsp

```
<g:javascript>

function ${controller}CloseModal() {
  var myClone=$('#BuildModal${id}').clone();
    $('#BuildModal${id}').dialog().dialog('close');
   $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
   $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
//var myCloner = myClone.clone();
   $('#${divId}1').hide().append(myClone);
     //$('body').append(myClone);

<g:if test="${!disablecheck.equals('true') }">
var controller="${controller }";
var divId="${divId }";
$.get('${createLink(controller:"MailingListEmail", action: "getAjaxCall")}?ccontroller='+controller+'&divId='+divId,function(data){
$('#${divId}').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
});
</g:if> 
}
</g:javascript>
```

The bits at the top of the function is all the things I have tried so far.
https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ml-test/blob/master/grails-app/views/mailingListEmail/contactclients.gsp

```
<div class="tbutton">
  <button href="#BuildModalSENDERS" class="btn btn-block btn-success" role="button" data-toggle="modal" title="Configure New Sender">
  New Sender?</button>
<div id="mailerSenders1">
  <g:render template="/mailingListModal/modalcreate" model="[title:'Add Senders Email', controller: 'mailingListSenders', callPage: 'form' , divId: 'mailerSenders', id: 'SENDERS' ]" />
  </div>
```

And finally modelForm which is included on the top of the modalcreate.gsp (now shown)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="BuildModal${id}" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
<div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>

     <g:formRemote id="${controller}" name="urlParams" class="form-horizontal" url="[controller:controller, action:'save']"
              update="BuildModal${id}" onComplete="${controller}CloseModal()"
              >
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
<h3>${title }</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
<g:render template="/${controller }/${callPage }"/>
<g:submitToRemote class="myformsubmit" url="[controller:controller, action:'save']" update="BuildModal${id}" onComplete="${controller}CloseModal()" value="Create" />
</div>
</div>
</g:formRemote>

</div>
</div>
</div>


  </div>
```

So it is a remote Form that submits can calls the above CloseModal

The question is when I Close this how do I make it available again  when the user clicks the button to create new email ?

After adding all the cloning at the top of java script the only difference I was able to make was to make it display the backdrop on 2nd click so it went black on 2nd click but did not show up the modal content.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it working by doing this:

```
 <button href="#BuildModalSENDERS" class="btn btn-block btn-success" role="button" data-toggle="modal" title="Configure New Sender"
```

Now adding

```
onClick="runCheck()"> .....

        <g:javascript>
        function runCheck() {
            $('#mailerSenders1').show();
        }
        </g:javascript>
```

That seems to work fine, it now loads up the page, just to add when I did body it just loaded it up again from the commented out attempts, modal.hide etc did not work and the hide attempts just showed it up under some other layers of the same page.. anyways this works fine now. sorry